# SAP Crystal Reports backward compatibilty

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have built a WPF Application in the past using Visual Studio 2010. I create Crystal Reports in my application. I installed the Crystal Studio for Visual Studio 2010 13.0.4 (which was the latest at that time). At client machine, I just installed the Crystal Reports Runtime Engine 13.0.4 and my application worked perfectly.

Recently, at a client machine I had to reinstalled the application and I downloaded the latest runtime engine from the [SAP Website](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) which was 13.0.13. But my application crashed whenever it was trying to load the Crystal Report in the application.

What is the possible cause for this? What do I need to do to make my application work with latest version of CR Runtime? Why is it not backward compatible?

Note: I fixed the issue by installing again CR Runtime Engine 13.0.4 on the client machine (fortunately the link still work on the website, although they don't show it as available).

Comment: I have deployed on over thousands of computer applications that i made that was using CRE 13.0.1(2,3,4,8 and 10). i have seen this issue quite often. i do not know why but yes reinstalling the run times fixes it.

Comment: Do you also get these incompatibility issues? I mean, if we develop using a particular version, is it a requirement that we need RE for the same version?

Comment: i had issue with some report designed in 13.0.10 opened with runtime 13.0.1 where date grouping and sorted was all wacky. but updating to sp3 or more fix the issue. onyl happen when datasources are DataSet and report are desgin with XSD schema.